# Compare two fields in GraphQL Hasura

Tags: graphql, hasura

I want to filter graphQL on two fields in Hasura. For example:

```
table (
    where: { field1: {_gt: field2}}
  ) {
    id
  }
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

No, you'll need to create a PG function that does this for you and query it via Hasura.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a "generated column" called field1_gt_field2 (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html, based on https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/1387), or a postgres "view" of the table where this filter is applied at postgres level. The equivalent for this on the mutation side is "ceq" or "column equals" but not available for queries (see https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/457).